# Google fit history API won't retrieve dataset?

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-fit

I am currently trying to display today's current steps through my application. I have the following code below which Authenticates most of the time alright. I have added the `SHA1` certificate to the developers console as well.

1. I keep getting the error "There was a problem inserting the dataset." in my log through with nothing else after that showing up and i'm a bit confused as to why?
2. Also this seems to be temperamental, sometimes it works and shows 7 data sets with random numbers (not my step count) so my second question is how do I get it to display just today's?

**Authentication**

```
private void buildFitnessClient() {
    if (mClient == null) {
        mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(
                        new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                                // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
                                new InsertAndVerifyDataTask().execute();


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                                // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                                if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                } else if (i
                                        == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                    Log.i(TAG,
                                            "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " +
                                result.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " +
                                result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                })
                .build();
    }


}
```

**Where I think the issue resides.**

```
private class InsertAndVerifyDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //First, create a new dataset and insertion request.
        DataSet dataSet = insertFitnessData();

        // [START insert_dataset]
        // Then, invoke the History API to insert the data and await the result, which is
        // possible here because of the {@link AsyncTask}. Always include a timeout when calling
        // await() to prevent hanging that can occur from the service being shutdown because
        // of low memory or other conditions.
        Log.i(TAG, "Inserting the dataset in the History API");

        com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status insertStatus =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, dataSet)
                        .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        // Before querying the data, check to see if the insertion succeeded.
        if (!insertStatus.isSuccess()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem inserting the dataset.");
            return null;
        }

        // At this point, the data has been inserted and can be read.
        Log.i(TAG, "Data insert was successful!");
        // [END insert_dataset]

        // Begin by creating the query.
        DataReadRequest readRequest = queryFitnessData();

        // [START read_dataset]
        // Invoke the History API to fetch the data with the query and await the result of
        // the read request.
        DataReadResult dataReadResult =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        // [END read_dataset]

        // For the sake of the sample, we'll print the data so we can see what we just added.
        // In general, logging fitness information should be avoided for privacy reasons.
        printData(dataReadResult);

        return null;
    }
}


private DataSet insertFitnessData() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating a new data insert request");

    // [START build_insert_data_request]
    // Set a start and end time for our data, using a start time of 1 hour before this moment.
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    // Create a data source
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(this)
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setName(TAG + " - step count")
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    // Create a data set
    int stepCountDelta = 1000;
    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
    // For each data point, specify a start time, end time, and the data value -- in this case,
    // the number of new steps.
    DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint()
            .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).setInt(stepCountDelta);
    dataSet.add(dataPoint);
    // [END build_insert_data_request]

    return dataSet;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the following code gets todays steps:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        cal.setTime(now);
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();


        int steps = 0;
        DataSource ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = new DataSource.Builder()
                .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
                .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
                .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms").build();

        // fill result with just the steps from the start and end time of the present day
        PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(mClient, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
        DailyTotalResult totalResult = result.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (totalResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            DataSet totalSet = totalResult.getTotal();
            steps = totalSet.isEmpty() ? -1 : totalSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
        }

        s = String.valueOf(steps);

        DataReadRequest readRequest = queryFitnessData();

        DataReadResult dataReadResult =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        feedItemList.clear();

        printData(dataReadResult);
        return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime, we also want to get data step in a specific time range, and here it's a reason in that case.

There're some probable causes:

1) Have you subscribed this type of data yet?

2) Your app doesn't connect properly with google service. Have you created OAuth Client ID from Google develop console? This's compulsory in instruction of google to connect to its GG Fit service (Please notice that, if you clone another app, on the same computer or not, you need to re-create another OAuth Client ID and one more thing you need 2 separated account, one to login Google develop console to create OAuth Client ID and one to sign in after starting your app, and it will ask you to sign in to accept its permission,... not sure why it's is, but it would work)

Note: Btw you can make a search about Google setting in your device (Setting --> Google), Here you can find which app connects to google service (including GG Fit service). I recommend you disconnect all and delete OAuth Client ID, your app, then re-create all of them!

Mttdat.